# How to implement bottom-position for IE6?And does the same problem still exist for IE5，say,all earlier versions?

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-6

No matter how you scroll, the `div` should always be at the bottom of the web page. Is there a solution using jQuery?

**EDIT**:

Should make it work in IE6.

Comment: Is there a reason you want this done with javascript/jQuery rather than with css?

Comment: @Shore, instead of adding the same comment to multiple answers, update the question. If you require IE6 support then you should have specified that.

Comment: you haven't upvoted answers on any more than 1/16 of your questions? Do that few really merit upvotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<html>
 <head>
  <style type="text/css">
   #theFooter {
    position:absolute;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    background-color:blue;
   }
  </style>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $("document").ready(function () {
   function recalculate(event) {
    var footer = $("#theFooter");
    var theWindow = $(window);
    var elementHeight = footer.height();
    var windowHeight = theWindow.height();
    var scrollTop = theWindow.scrollTop();
    footer.css("top", windowHeight - elementHeight + scrollTop);
   }
   $(window).bind("resize scroll", recalculate);
   recalculate();
  });
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div id="theFooter">
  Some Content.
 </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Since only IE6 don't obey position:fixed,I think you'd better make it only apply to IE6,right?

Comment: Yes, because this wastes a lot more CPU cycles than the simple CSS does.

Comment: How to make your code only apply to IE6?BTW,will IE5 also have this problem?

Comment: Use conditional comments: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html
IE5 has probably the same error but isn't supported by jQuery anyway.

Answer (score 3):

No need of javascript. CSS could do that...

```
#footer { 
  position: fixed; 
  width: 100%; 
  height: 50px; 
  left: 0; 
  bottom: 0 
}
```

Comment: That would be position: fixed

Answer (score 2):

position:fixed is the solution for all browsers but ie6

There's plenty of solutions to make position fixed to work with ie6

But all time you'll do it you'll loose some other functionnality in other browsers (position:relative and absolute loosed), or you'll need css expressions and they will slow down the browser

http://www.cssplay.co.uk/layouts/fixed.html (css loose of relative and absolute)
http://tagsoup.com/cookbook/css/fixed/bottom/
http://limpid.nl/lab/css/fixed/footer

Seriously stop developing for ie6 ! :)

Comment: Not having to develop for IE6 is often just a dream. Since often in professional environments your clients require backward compatibility till IE6 and that's a nightmare.

Comment: All companies staying behind ie6 are just laizyyy, switching from ie6 to ie7 doesn't require much change in code !

Javascript and css in ie6 have less functions, habilities than in ie7, there's no real reason to stay with ie6 but fear and not controlling how your apps really works !

Modifying 100 lines of css/javascript is harder than not touching anything, i understand :)

BUT i also understed that when you're dealing with clients, you can't argue like that but i'll definitely say no to someone asking me to develop a new site under ie6.

Comment: Is position:fixed the solution for IE5.5 then?

Comment: NOPE !

Is this solution acceptable ? :) You have all the keys to change your code

Answer (score 0):

To set the appropriate style with jQuery you can do:

```
$('#footer').css({ 
  position: "fixed", 
  width: "100%",
  height: "50px", 
  left: 0, 
  bottom: 0 
});
```

Comment: I fixed missing quotes. Apart from this, I don't know why I have been downvoted. Man asked how he can do it with jQuery. Maybe he wants to do it on some event? Pure css solutions would be useless in that case.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style type="text/css">
#bottom {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score -3):

You can achieve that with pure css. Here's an excerpt (taken from http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-en/msg/3b877c156facb54d):

```
#footer { 
        position: absolute; 
        height: 50px; 
        width: 300px; 
        bottom: 0px; 
        left: 10px; 
}
```

Comment: He said "No matter how you scroll". So, I think 'position' should be 'fix'.